# Getting Parameter by index of a function type

Tags: typescript

I have a function type:

```
export interface NativeMethods {

measureLayout(
        relativeToNativeComponentRef: HostComponent<unknown> | number,
        onSuccess: MeasureLayoutOnSuccessCallback,
        onFail: () => void /* currently unused */,
    ): void;

}
```

This is actually in a lib. I want to get the type of each parameter like this pseudo-code:

type Param1 = Parameters<NativeMethod.measureLayout>[0];

however it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an *indexed access type* ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)), like this:

```
type Param1 = Parameters<NativeMethods['measureLayout']>[0];
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gZ2AYTgWzHAdhLwA8AKgHxQC8UA3gL4BQokUAshAIYICuAThADKsg4HYAHksAZQ4BjKRAQJkrADZKARqykBrclTq0IAD0xdgUAJZ4IXAGYboAOVbAzANwgtgACzgATBFVpaNDZOHn5BYQAKWihYuNieJSdXCEI4R2c3VAxsXGAAJQhrAC5YRBR0TBw8fA4sTSw4AHcsUgAfKCwONFUrABoY%20LjsSRk5BFKWdm4%20ASFRCWlZeUUVdS0BoeGsADFWMyVSyIBKclIXODMfKAB6ACooKW4ePCUQKDqOBAhru5vNuLHUoXK4AbkCehuNyghE8Zn88KgGmAHGUb3MWCRUCUZlUADooABJKBNVh4KDAOBQADmEFMXmgDGgcGsUDYUk8UDArC4rGCwCs2LMmkZcP8YG%20HB8cAAtFJfBBioEmVAAAo8vkARh06t5-KsCHwGRSHm8fgA2gByYLTMJzYSWgC6xHNAAZHaCgA)